# Spring Boot with HTML Text Editor

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, ckeditor, thymeleaf

I have integrated CKeditor with my spring boot project and all works well. However, when I insert data through the integrated CKeditor, the returned data/text does not show styled the way it is styled before it is inserted into my MySql table. For example, this is how I would insert the data:

**Heading**

Text Description

Once I retrieve this text/blog from the database, it looks like below:

```
<h1>Heading</h1> <p>Text Description</p>
```

How can I get the inserted text styled the same way it was inserted into my tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution to my problem for anybody who has the same problem. Thymeleaf now has its own tag to remove or escape html tags.

This is what I was using before:

```
<p th:text="${singlePostJob.jobtext}"></p>
```

The above line would return data as texts instead of escaped texts. However, if you use `th:utext` instead, it would escape HTML tags and returned your text styled the way you insert them into your tables. So instead of the above line, I have used the following and it works perfectly:

```
<p th:utext="${singlePostJob.jobtext}"></p>
```